# Markov Trace and Markov Property

Tags: knot-theory, braid-groups, st.statistics

Hey guys,

I'm a computer science student attempting to understand a quantum algorithm that uses braid theory - something I'm completely unfamiliar.  I've getting through the algorithm but I can't find any simple explanations of the following terms:

- Markov Trace
- Markov Property

For example, the following article tells me what a Markov trace is but it's out of my zone a bit:

@ARTICLE{markov,
   author = {{Orellana}, R. and {Ram}, A.},
    title = "{Affine braids, Markov traces and the category O}",
  journal = {ArXiv Mathematics e-prints},
   eprint = {arXiv:math/0401317},
 keywords = {Representation Theory},
     year = 2004,
    month = jan,
   adsurl = {http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2004math......1317O},
  adsnote = {Provided by the SAO/NASA Astrophysics Data System}
}

Can anyone explain what they are very simply?  Thank you :).

EDIT: Sorry for being not specific enough, this is the paper I'm referring to:

@article{tutte,
    Author = {Aharonov D and Arad I and Eban E and Landau Z},
    Journal = {Arxiv preprint quant-ph/0702008},
    Title = {Polynomial Quantum Algorithms for Additive approximations of the Potts model and other Points of the Tutte Plane},
    Year = {2007}}

I'm trying to get my head around how the Tutte polynomial is approximated using tensor networks in quantum computing.  This is perhaps too specific now!

Comment: Perhaps say what you are trying to read.  That way MO would know which Markov property is being referred to... 

Comment: I've made an EDIT - see original post.  Thank you :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want section 2.11 of reference [6] of the paper you are looking at, namely "A Polynomial Quantum Algorithm for Approximating the Jones Polynomial" at the [arxiv](http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0511096v2).